# Unable to get values from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, maps

**I am making udacity project of neighbourhood maps in which I have to tag location and when the marker is clicked it should display information from another API.I am able to fetch data from API but not able to append to my infoblock.
Below i am providing full code:**

when i try making call from line 94 i dont get any array.I need data in line 96 to append the infobox.I am not able to get data from popContent function.

```js
var map;
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': 'app_id',
    'app_code': 'app_code'
});
// Obtain the default map types from the platform object:
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
// Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    defaultLayers.normal.map,
    {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: 19.0760, lng: 72.8777 }
    });
// Create the default UI:
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
//data for marker
var Location = function(title,lat, lng){
    var self = this;
    this.title = title;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lng;
    //get content of marker location
    this.popContent = function(newtitle,newlat,newlon){
        var markerarray = [];
        var foursquareURL = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll='+newlat+','+newlon+'&client_id=&client_secret=&v=20180908&query='+newtitle+'';
        //Using Foursquare API to get info about the restaurant
        $.getJSON(foursquareURL).done(function(data) {
            var results = data.response.venues[0];
            self.name = results.name;
            self.street = results.location.formattedAddress[0];
            self.city = results.location.formattedAddress[1]; 
            self.postalCode  = results.location.postalCode;
            markerarray.push(self.name,self.street,self.city,self.postalCode);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("There was an error with the Foursquare API call. Please refresh the page and try again to load Foursquare data.");
        }); 
        return markerarray;
    };
    //info window
    this.addMarkerToGroup = function (group, coordinate, html) {
        var marker = new H.map.Marker(coordinate);
        // add custom data to the marker
        marker.setData(html);
        group.addObject(marker);
    };
    //open infowindow for location marker
    this.openinfowindow = function(map) {
        var group = new H.map.Group();
        map.addObject(group);
        // add 'tap' event listener, that opens info bubble, to the group
        group.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
            // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
            // for all objects that it contains
            var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
                // read custom data
                content: evt.target.getData()
            });
            // show info bubble
            ui.addBubble(bubble);
        }, false);
        var datahtml =  this.popContent(this.title,this.lat,this.lon);
        this.addMarkerToGroup(group, {lat:this.lat, lng:this.lon},'<div><a href="#" >'+datahtml[0]+'</a>' + '</div><div >'+datahtml[1]+'<br>' + datahtml[2]+'<br>'+datahtml[3]+'</div>');
    };
    this.openinfowindow(map);
    //assign click event for marker
};
var locationsModel = {
    //array
    locations:[
        new Location('Kanjurmarg',19.1317,72.9352),
        new Location('Thane', 19.2183, 72.9781),
        new Location('Powai', 19.1197, 72.9051),
        ],
        query: ko.observable(''),
};
// Search function for filtering through the list of locations based on the name of the location.
locationsModel.search = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    var self = this;
    var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations, function(location) {
        return location.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
}, locationsModel);
//search function  for filtering locations
ko.applyBindings(locationsModel);
```

```css
#map{
 height: 400px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Neighborhood project</title>
 <!-- optimum performance on mobile device -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
 <!-- loads the module -->
 <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
   type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
   type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" 
       type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
       href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <!-- custom stylesheet -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
   <h2>Neighborhood Maps</h2> 
    <div id="map"></div>
    


    <div class="search-area" id="search-area">
        <input class="search-input" placeholder="Search for Places..." type="text" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
        <ul class="location-list" data-bind="visible:query, template: {name: 'location', foreach: search}">
        </ul>
      </div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="js/knockout-3.4.2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snipet isn't working. Removing all the stuff like `head` tag and instead put those links as resources by clicking 'Add external library' and what add whatever you need one by one. Also remove the link to `test.js`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `$.getJSON` inside `popContent` is asynchronous and it doesn't return values immediately. In your code `this.popContent()` will always return empty array.

What you need to do is make your code dependent on that `$.getJSON` response. First way is to wrap all in the callback of `$.getJSON`. Second way is to use promises.